# erb won't render in coffeescript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb

I'm having trouble figuring out why our ruby code isn't rendering in coffeescript. Ultimately we're working towards plotting a series of markers stored in a Rails model in a Google Maps view. Because we had trouble with a loop, we tried to get a test variable to render in an alert; it's not working. The alert pops up, but it says only *Hello*, not *Hello 5* (or *Hello "5"* ?)

This is our coffeescript file (locations.coffee.erb)

```
$ ->
    alert "Hello <%= @test %>"
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.0, -107.0);
    myOptions =
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.0, -107.0);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        title: "Test",
    });
```

@test is defined in #map, at the bottom of locations_controller.rb:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @traveling_party = TravelingParty.find_by_id(session[:party])
        @location = Location.where("position >= #{@traveling_party.position}").order("position ASC").first
    end

    def move
        f = params[:traveling_party]

        @traveling_party = TravelingParty.find(f["id"])
        @traveling_party.speed = f["speed"].to_i
        @traveling_party.ration = f["ration"].to_i

        @location = Location.where("position > #{@traveling_party.position}").order("position ASC").first

        @traveling_party.position += @traveling_party.speed
        if @traveling_party.position > @location.position 
            @traveling_party.position = @location.position
        end

        food_eaten = @traveling_party.ration * @traveling_party.people
        Item.where({:trader_id => @traveling_party.id, :type => "Food"}).limit(food_eaten).destroy_all()

        if @traveling_party.save()
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated traveling party."
            redirect_to '/play/'
        else
            flash[:error] = "Transaction could not be completed."
            redirect_to '/play/'
        end
    end

    def map
        @traveling_party = TravelingParty.find_by_id(session[:party])
        @locations = Location.all
        @test = "5"
    end

end
```

What seems strange to me is that @test is rendering properly in our map.html.erb view. As expected, 5 is printed above the map:

```
<% @locations.each do |loc| %>

<% end %>

<div id="map_canvas">Random</div>
```

Comment: Where's your `locations.coffee.erb` file? If it's in the `assets`, then it'll be processed only once and will not have the context of your current requests at this time... So your ERB doesn't know a lot about your extrapolations.

Comment: @Romain - locations.coffee.erb is in assets/javascripts. Would we fix this issue if we placed the javascript in map.html.erb and got rid of locations.coffee.erb entirely?

Comment: @apneadiving - That does seem like it'd solve our problem... Although I'm new to Rails, so it might be easier to write this from scratch rather than grapple with gems

Comment: @jmaliakal You'll probably save some sanity by using gems rather than trying to write from scratch. And to answer your question - yes it'd fix your issue, but it'd be considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

The file is indeed being run through ERB, but only once - when the application is precompiling assets. And this isn't something you can change very easily, and you probably shouldn't try.

What you could do instead is fetch the actual data that you want populated separately via an AJAX JSON request or maybe embed it as Javascript in your page template.

The ERB compilation of static (CSS + JS) files is normally used to put in environment specific data that doesn't change with each request.